# Is there Shape Metrics Toolbox or equivalent for ArcGIS 10?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, polygon, geometry, error-999999

I need to compute the geometric properties (e.g. contiguity index, dispersion index etc.) of a series of polygons and I would like to use the [**Shape Metrics Toolbox**](http://clear.uconn.edu/tools/Shape_Metrics/download.htm).

I am using ArcGis 10 and the version of the toolbox that I could find on the website is said to be for ArcGis 9.3. When I try to use the tool I get an error message which might be related to an incompatibility with ArcGis 10:

```
ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
<type 'exceptions.SystemExit'>: 1
Failed to execute (ShapeMetrics).
```

I found several papers on line in which the authors mention an ArcGis 10 version of the Shape Metrics Tool but I couldn't find this version anywhere. I have contacted the authors but have received no reply yet.

I was wondering whether any of you have experience with the Shape Metrics toolbox in ArcGis 10,  have encountered the error message above or know of other user-written tools for ArcGis 10 which compute shape metrics.

Comment: As an alternative, you may want to take a look at the V-Late extension. http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=36f9728a895e4f5386bdec68be6d08ac

Comment: I think this is a related question to the original question, and it makes sense in the context of the provided answers.Please do not delete this post. I downloaded the edited script. I am running into error messages as well. Do you have a suggestion how to fix it with no programming skills? Thank you for any advice. Error Message: Traceback (most recent call last): line 432, in main(*argv) line 251, in main perimPntLst = Helper_tool.PerimeterPnts(vertexLst, 500) Helper_tool.py", line 550, in PerimeterPnts x1 = (-B + (B2-4*A*C).5) / (2*A) ValueError: negative number cannot be raised to a fracti

Answer (score 4):

We rarely used the Toolbox within ArcGIS 10.x.

The problem was with several bugs in the Toolbox's Python script.

We have fixed the problems and now it works with ArcGIS 10.x.

If you need the fixed toolbox, do not hesitate to contact me and I will send it.  (I am one of the authors.)

Answer (score 1):

I've edited the Shape Metrics scripts to work in 10.x. I've tested it in ArcGIS 10.4, it should run in 10.0 too. I've included all necessary files - tbx,py,pdf,etc .
[Shape_Metrics.py for ArcGIS 10.x](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1U2lmfuFE7_0ucfim8ziyrpjAmoPcujN7?usp=sharing)

Comment: above link is not working, can you please update.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to track down an ArcGIS 10.x version of the Shape Metrics toolbox by contacting the authors of [this paper](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-971/paper13.pdf) which mentions it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Whitebox tools provide a range of shape metric tools as discussed in the [manual](https://jblindsay.github.io/wbt_book/available_tools/gis_analysis_patch_shape_tools.html). The only limitation is that input data needs to be in shapefile format. The tools have been exposed as user friend geoprocessing tools and the toolbox can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/giswqs/WhiteboxTools-ArcGIS).